# How to upgrade gerrit version?

Tags: upgrade, gerrit

I would like to install the last [Gerrit releases](https://www.gerritcodereview.com/releases/README.md) on a working Gerrit instance.

Is it enought to [download last war package](https://gerrit-releases.storage.googleapis.com/index.html) then paste under `InstallFolder/bin/gerrit.war`.

Do I need to redo the `init` process : `java -jar gerrit.war init -d site_path` ?

---

As example, I want to upgrade from 2.12.2 to 2.13 and I can read on 2.13 relase note

> This release contains schema changes. To upgrade:  java -jar gerrit.war init -d site_path

Do I have to redo the action under [Important Notes section](https://www.gerritcodereview.com/releases/2.13.md#Important-Notes) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. You NEED to execute:

```
java -jar gerrit.war init -d site_path
```

To upgrade the database schema and to install the new available "hooks" core plugin. You don't need to copy the gerrit.war file to the InstallFolder/bin path, the init procedure will do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming across here having this error:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException
```

Just go to /bin and do

```
sudo ./gerrit.sh stop
```